# Exchange server behind Cisco router

Tags: exchange-server, cisco

I have Cisco 2801 router with public IP and NAT enabled effectively providing Internet access to users behind it. 
How to publish Exchange server behind the router using above mentioned Public IP so users can send/receive emails while not in the office using Outlook as well as with OWA and Mobile ActiveSync.

BR,
Oleg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to open ports that are required for Inbound access on the Cisco 2801. Assuming that you want to open port 443 for the OWA on server 10.1.1.1, you will enter something like the following

ip nat inside source static tcp 10.1.1.1 443 interface Fa 0/0 443

Where Fa 0/0 is the Interface connected to the Internet.

Be careful when you open ports; you need to have good understanding of Firewalls and Security design of your Network.

Answer (score 1):

You will add Destination nat on cisco router for users can access to your Exchange server from internet. and you must create Access list for open necessary port for Exchange server like https, smtp, pop3, imap , TCP/587, tcp/993, tcp/995 and by default other things will block with hidden rule on ACL.

Destination NAT
ip nat inside source static   
Access list 
ip access-list extended OUTSIDE-TO-INSIDE_AL
10 permit tcp any  eq 443 
.
.
.
.
You can use Zone-Base firewall, if your device and IOS are support it.